# R replace the column name by the dataframe name with a map-function

Tags: r, map-function

I have a problem replace the column name by the dataframe name with a map-function. I have 25 dataframes with cryptocurrency time series data.

```
ls(pattern="USD")
[1] "ADA.USD"   "BCH.USD"   "BNB.USD"   "BTC.USD"   "BTG.USD"   "DASH.USD"      "DOGE.USD"  "EOS.USD"   "ETC.USD"   "ETH.USD"   "IOT.USD"
[12] "LINK.USD"  "LTC.USD"   "NEO.USD"   "OMG.USD"   "QTUM.USD"  "TRX.USD"   "USDT.USD"  "WAVES.USD" "XEM.USD"   "XLM.USD"   "XMR.USD"
[23] "XRP.USD"   "ZEC.USD"   "ZRX.USD"
```

Every object is a dataframe which stands for a cryptocurrency expressed in USD. And every dataframe has 2 clomuns: Date and Close (Closing price). For example: the dataframe "BTC.USD" stands for Bitcoin in USD:

```
head(BTC.USD)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
Date       Close
1 2015-12-31  430.
2 2016-01-01  434.
3 2016-01-02  434.
4 2016-01-03  431.
5 2016-01-04  433.
```

Now I want to replace the name of the second column ("Close") by the name of the dataframe ("BTC.USD")

For this case I used the following code:

```
colnames(BTC.USD)[2] <-deparse(substitute(BTC.USD))
```

And this code works as I imagined:

```
head(BTC.USD)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
Date       BTC.USD
1 2015-12-31    430.
2 2016-01-01    434.
3 2016-01-02    434.
```

Now I am trying to rename all "Close"-columns for all 25 dataframes of cryptocurrency data with a map-function:

```
names_of_dataframes <- ls.str(mode = "list")
map(names_of_dataframes, colnames(x)[2] <- names_of_dataframes[[i]])
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the datasets into `list` with `mget`, loop through the `list` with `imap`, `rename` the 2nd column with `.y` which gives the `data.frame` object name

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(ls(pattern="USD")) %>%         
              imap(~ {nm1 <- .y
                      .x %>% 
                         rename_at(2, ~ nm1) })
```

Comment: Or maybe something like `mget(ls(pattern="USD")) %>% bind_rows(id = "curr")`

Comment: Yes, thanks. (I missed that when reading args(dplyr::bind_rows) and didn't have example data to test on.)

Comment: Many thanks! This code works. But the code does not overwrite the 25 data frames. How can I save this for all 25 dataframes?

Comment: @T.Kel. I would keep it in a `list` instead.  But, if you want to overwrite, then do `lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "USD")) %>% ...; list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobalEnv)`